# linq condition to accept null dictionary(Value) if not passed by treating it as null

Tags: c#, linq

I have this validation where it checks whether  key and value are valid  or not in the Dictionary  but have to modify it to accept null Key Dictionary and treat it as an Empty collection while checking for inner key and value

change the logic to accept value as null for the Dictionary

```
List<KeyValuePair<string, Dictionary<string, string>>> properties = new List<KeyValuePair<string, Dictionary<string, string>>>();
properties.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, Dictionary<string, string>>("test", null));
var list = properties.Select(cat => cat.Value.Keys.Any(key => string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(key) || cat.Value.Values.Any(value => string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(value))));
```

It is being failed when i pass null. please let me know what i need to change in select statement to treat null as an Empty inner Dictionary

Answer (score 2):

since you want to treat null value Dictionary as empty and empty dictionary doesn't have keys or values, you should probably ignore null values:

```
var list = properties.Where(p => p.Value != null)
           .Select(cat => cat.Value.Keys.Any(key => string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(key) 
                       || cat.Value.Values.Any(value => string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(value))));
```

Answer (score 1):

You need check `cat.Value` for `null` before access to it property:

```
    var properties = new List<KeyValuePair<string, Dictionary<string, string>>>
    {
        new KeyValuePair<string, Dictionary<string, string>>("test", null)
    };
    var list = properties.Select(cat => cat.Value != null && (cat.Value.Keys.Any(key => string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(key) || cat.Value.Values.Any(string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace))));
```

Or you can do this:

```
    var list = properties
        .Select(kvp=> new KeyValuePair<string, Dictionary<string,string>>(kvp.Key, kvp.Value ?? new Dictionary<string, string>()))
        .Select(cat => cat.Value.Keys.Any(key => string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(key) || cat.Value.Values.Any(string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace)));
```